# Hibernate sort based on enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I have am working a project which uses enums as columns to a database

```
public enum MyEnum{
 a1(1,"act1"),
 a2(2,"act2"),
 a3(3,"act3"),
 b1(4,"bob1"),
 c1(10,"cake1"),
 c2(11,"cake2"),
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity{
..

private Integer myEnumIntValue;

... 

}
```

(NOTE: myEnumIntValue is not mapped as enum in the entity)

I have a hibernate query to query MyEntity. The query orders the result based on the int value of the enum

```
createCriteria(MyEntity.class).addOrder("myEnumIntValue");
```

This was all good until the enum was changed to

```
Public enum MyEnum{
 a1(1,"act1"),
 a2(2,"act2"),
 a3(3,"act3"),
 a4(7,"act4"),
 b1(4,"bob1"),
 c1(10,"cake1"),
 c2(11,"cake2")
}
```

It now becomes a problem because the order of the result is i am getting is `(a1,a2,a3,**b1,a4**,c1,c2)` but sorting of the Entities should be `(a1,a2,a3,**a4,b1**,c1,c2)`

What is strategy can i use to resolve this?

Comment: So you want an `hibernate query that orders the query based on string value of the enum`?

Comment: the enum is saved as an Integer in the database so query is ordered based on the Integer value

Comment: Then your only solution is the one I posted, actually you're in the `can't manipulate the query` part of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want / can't manipulate the query to order the enums while fetching, remember that all enums implement the [`Comparable interface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

You can override the `compareTo()` method and do the sorting direclty from your java code.

To get specific:

```
public enum MyEnum{
 a1(1,"act1"),
 a2(2,"act2"),
 a3(3,"act3"),
 b1(4,"bob1"),
 c1(10,"cake1"),
 c2(11,"cake2");

 private number;
 private name;

 public MyEnum(Integer number, String name){
     this.number = number;
     this.name = name;
 }

 //getters and setters

 @Override
 public int compareTo(MyEnum otherEnum){
     return this.getName().compareTo(otherEnum.getName());
 }

}
```

As soon as you have your `List<MyEnum> myList` fetched from the DB, you only have to call:

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

to get your enums sorted via `name`.

Comment: I need the sorting if possible in the query (ie. criteria.addOrder or something like setting projection) because the criteria is passed to a "Paging" object(ie. the query should kind of already sorted when it's passed to the paging object")

Comment: Well, but if you don't have a reference of `name` in your DB is simply impossible to order by `name` in the query.

Comment: @user3308224 Also, how do you populate the `name` field having only the `number` from DB?

Comment: The enum is part of MyEntity. If an instance of MyEntity is type a1 then its myEnumIntValue field has value of 1. If another instance of MyEntity is b4 then its myEnumIntValue filed is 4. What I am querying is the list of MyEntity (not the enum). So I have a table of MyEntity which has a column myEnumIntValue, which corresponds to the enum